# Using __NR_in userspace code

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, header-files, system-calls

I have a code which checks the presence of certain system calls via something like

```
#if defined(__NR_process_vm_readv)

blah blah

#else 

blah2 blah2

#endif
```

After running the source file through the pre-processor I see that the code in `#else` is being compiled. The reason is that the the `unistd.h` which is included resides under `/usr/include`  whereas the unistd.h file which has those particular defines is under `/usr/include/asm-generic/unistd.h`. So how am I supposed to include it? The code I'm working has been written by a 3rd party so I don't know if the strategy that they opted to follow is even correct (relying on those defines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this on linux is shown in the syscall(2) manual page (see for example http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
```

possibly with a preceding "#define _GNU_SOURCE" or other system specifier, though that doesn't seem to be necessary on my system. The `<sys/syscall.h>` file actually includes `<asm/unistd.h>`. This provides the SYS_syscall definition as well as __NR_syscall